# Solve $\log(z^2-1)=\frac{i\pi}{2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, complex-numbers, logarithms

I was wondering if someone could help me solve the following complex logarithmic equation, such that $$
\text{Log}(z):=\log(z) \iff\arg z=\theta_p
$$

$$
\forall z \in \mathbb{R} :\text{Log}(z^2-1)=i\pi/2
$$

So far, I have

$$
w=e^z \implies w^2+w+1=0.
$$
Solving for $w$ using quadratic
$$
w=-1/2+i\sqrt3/2
$$
or$$
w=-1/2-i\sqrt3/2
$$
From the text, I know a few things
$$
\text{Log}(z)=\text{Log}(r)+i\theta_p : r=|z|>0, \theta_p=\arg(z), -\pi<\theta_p<=\pi
$$
$$
\text{Arg}(z)=\theta_p+2\pi k : k=..., -3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, ...
$$
$$
\log(z)=\text{Log}(r)+i(\theta+2 \pi k)
$$

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: $e^{i\pi /2}=i$. Solve $z^{2}-1=i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

Eliminate the natural logarithm on both sides, i.e. $$\exp(\log (z^2 -1)) = \exp \left(\dfrac {i \pi}{2}\right)$$ Also notice that $$\exp \left(\dfrac {i \pi}{2}\right) \rightarrow \cos \dfrac {\pi}{2} +i \sin \dfrac {\pi}{2} = 0 + i (1) = i$$

Can you take it from here?